# SSRS rdl preview shows date with bad value shows up despite SQL query that should exclude it

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, reporting-services, rdl

SSRS rdl preview shows date with bad value shows up despite SQL query that should exclude it.

The xml for the query in the rdl-file is:

```
  <Query>
    <DataSourceName>ourDataSource</DataSourceName>
    <CommandText>
      use ourDataBase
      ----------------------------------------
      select convert(date, Date1) as ourDate1, count(*) as ourCountForDate
      from ourDataBase.dbo.ourTable
      where
      (
          (Date1 between (getDate()-365) and (getDate()+1) )
      )
      group by convert(date, Date1)
      order by convert(date, Date1)
    </CommandText>
    <rd:UseGenericDesigner>true</rd:UseGenericDesigner>
  </Query>
```

This query works just fine in the SQL database when using TSQL directly in SSMS.

However, there is a stray value with a strange year in the database (such as 7654), and it shows up in the results for the rdl file in 'preview' but *NOT* in the SQL-query results in SSMS.

I have tried lots of variants, with greater than or equal to, and so forth, but this stray value always shows up.

I am using SSRS, Visual Studio 2015, with underlying TSQL. The SSRS uses 2016/01/reportdefinition.  The SQL server for the project is SQL Server 2008 R2, 2012 or 2014.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to create a stored procedure in SQL Server and then have the SSRS call that. Can perform better too. This keeps the data control entirely in the SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

For those not wanting to use stored-procedures (e.g. due to having to migrate them from various database regions), this worked for me:

Deleting the associated ".data" file helped, also, 'clean' and 'rebuild' the project.

One can also try things like make sure the year starts with 2 (or for some is less than 3).
Here is how one checks for starting with 2:

> (  left(Datepart(yyyy, Date1),1) = '2' )